# How to make a bot respond exactly what you say in discord.py

Tags: discord.py

im trying to get my Discord bot to say exactly what i want with the command of !say excluding the !say part but im new to coding and have no idea where to start. I know the basics of making a bot say/react/delete/DM messages but thats all

Comment: Just create a command that takes two arguments `ctx` and `phrase`. Then `await ctx.send(phrase)` and the bot will repeat it. Note that you have to use `commands.Bot` for this, not `discord.Client`. For `discord.Client` you could split the messages by spaces and join a string starting from index 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```py
@commands.command()
    async def say(self, ctx, *, arg):
        await ctx.send(arg)
```

The full code would look something like this:

```py
from discord.ext import commands


bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=discord.Intents.all())


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("bot is ready")

@commands.command()
    async def say(self, ctx, *, arg):
        await ctx.send(arg)


bot.run("YOURTOKEN")
```